# WebBrowser performance issues

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to use many (5 to 10) WebBrowser controls in single WPF window. Some of them using JS and need to render graphics.

When the WebBrowsers are loading the pages the application is freeze for 10 minutes or more.

I've tried to use WebBroser of WPF and of Windows Form but they both suffering these performance issues.

When I remove to 2 WebBrowsers for example, the application runs well.

Is there any way to make better performance with WebBrowsers?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to display the web-pages inside your application? Could you instead load them in actual instances of `iexplore.exe` and use COM automation to control them?

Comment: The windows contains the WebBrowsers and more WPF controls. I am using WebBrowser to load some pages that library that I am using of give me. They all part of one window and should not be seperated

Comment: It kinda sounds like a "async vs sync" issue? can you init your web browser in another thread? then even they are slow, you'll not get a frozen screen.

Comment: They are in the XAML, how can I do that?